# apollo-link-rest: query with dynamic fields in response

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-link-rest

I'm requesting a Salesforce schema data. It has a format

```
res = {
  Id: { name, type, label },
  IsDeleted: { type, name, label },
  MasterRecordId: { type, name, label },
 ...and so on
}
```

So, fields are dynamic.
In queries.js I'm trying to describe it

```
export const GET_SALESFORCE_FIELDS = gql`
  query SalesforceFields {
    salesforceFields @rest(endpoint: "schemaservice", type: "SalesforceFields", path: "/fields") {
       // What should be here??
   }
  }
`;
`
```

How can I describe the dynamic part?
I don't have any schema files or resolvers. Only queries.js (for further requests with useQuery) and client.js (where the `new ApolloClient` is defined)

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.0.0-rc.10",
"apollo-link-rest": "^0.8.0-beta.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved in this way:

```
// queries.js
export const GET_SALESFORCE_FIELDS = gql`
  query SalesforceFields {
    salesforceFields @rest(endpoint: "schemaservice", type: "SalesforceFieldsPayload", path: "/fields") {
      items @type(name: "Salesforce")
    }
  }
`;

// client.js
const restLink = new RestLink({
  ...,
  typePatcher: {
    SalesforceFieldsPayload: (
      data,
      outerType,
      patchDeeper
    ) => {
      if (data != null) {
        data.items = Object.keys(data).map(field => ({ __typename: "Salesforce", ...data[field] }));
      }
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

A reference to GitHub: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-rest/issues/258

Comment: Thanks for this!